# How to run the main method of an Android Activity class?

Tags: java, android

I'd would like to examine a private method of an **Android Activity** by executing it within the Activity's ***public static void main(String[] args)*** method which I created.

I use **Eclipse ADT** and my naive approach of running the *Activity* as a **Java application** resulted in:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3174), pid=2936, tid=2980
>   Error: ShouldNotReachHere()

So I looked at the **Run Configuration** and found out that **Android 3.1** is the sole entry in the **Bootstrap Entries** section of **Classpath**. I managed to configure the **Build Path** of the project so that the **JRE** is in the **Bootstrap Entries** too. Then I removed the **Android 3.1** entry and added **android.jar** to **User Entries**.

The result of executing the **Run Configuration** is a RuntimeException:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
>     at android.content.Context.(Context.java:4)

**An alternative** of executing some tests would be to fire up a **JUnit** test. But in the case of a **private method** this is cumbersome.

Is there a way to successfully run the main method of an Android Activity class?

Comment: You can't fire up an `Activity` through a main method. The problem with trying this is that the system handles all construction of the four building blocks. Unless your [netbook runs Android](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-android-netbook/), you can't do this (but this only prevents you having to use an emulator). Related to the JUnit tests, Android SDK does come with a tool called [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) that you may want to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another option for the problem at hand, if the `private` method - which should be examined through the execution of a main method - can be **extracted to another class**. This of course means that the method suddenly became at least `protected`.

But if the method is definded within a class that does not derive from [android.app.Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) a **main method** can be defined. You only have to adjust the **Run Configuration** in Eclipse.

1. Run the class with **Run as Java Application**. This generates a new Run Configuration named like the class
2. Edit the newly creaded Run Configuration
3. Delete the **Android** library from **Bootstrap Entries** in the **Classpath** tab
4. Add JRE 6 or so to the build path of the project
5. Add this JRE to the **Bootstrap Entries** in the **Classpath** tab
6. Add **android.jar**, which resides in the **platforms** directory of the **Android SDK** in **User Entries** in the **Classpath** tab

Answer (score 2):

Activity is very important from Android's point of view, Activity's lifecycle are collections of few methods which are handled by OS through out the activities' life.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedBunldeInstance)
```

is called as soon as the App is launched creating the activity. This is the entry point of an application in android. You must have the emulator or physical device for running Android app, Here the file is `compiled 2 times`, once by `java compiler then by dalvik compiler`.

`DVM (Dalvik Virtual Machine)` is located on the Android device (EMULATOR OR PHYSICAL), this is the reason why we need emulator or physical device to run it..and onCreate is the entry point for it.

On your request I am editing this post with an additional piece of information. The lines below are abstracted from http://developer.android.com/

```
 Android applications don't have a single entry point.
 (there's no main() function, for example).
```

for further details click this :

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html
```

Comment: Thanks for outlining what's going on behind the scenes. Upvoted. This means that running a main method on Android's Activity classes is not achievable with a decent amount of effort, right? Would you like to edit your answer accordingly, if that's correct. Then I would accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main method isn't the entry point in Android like in Java. You wanna override the

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedBunldeInstance) method.
```

Comment: This would not allow me to execute code within onCreate without firing up the emulator or a physical device, right? But that's the whole point.

Comment: Nope. You cannot run anything without the emulator because you dont have Android Virtual Machine implemented for your architecture like you have Java Virtual Machine.