# Calling custom class/method in android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, parsing

I am a new android developer and this is my first question, so please bear with me...

I am trying to call a custom method in a class I made, but I get the following error in the console:

Logcat :

```
06-18 06:57:13.291: D/AndroidRuntime(1251): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-18 06:57:13.291: D/AndroidRuntime(1251): CheckJNI is ON
06-18 06:57:13.331: D/dalvikvm(1251): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-18 06:57:13.341: D/dalvikvm(1251): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-18 06:57:13.371: D/dalvikvm(1251): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-18 06:57:13.371: D/dalvikvm(1251): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-18 06:57:14.061: D/AndroidRuntime(1251): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-18 06:57:14.091: D/AndroidRuntime(1251): Shutting down VM
06-18 06:57:14.101: D/dalvikvm(1251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 94K, 18% free 469K/568K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 12ms
06-18 06:57:14.101: D/dalvikvm(1251): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-18 06:57:14.621: D/AndroidRuntime(1263): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-18 06:57:14.621: D/AndroidRuntime(1263): CheckJNI is ON
06-18 06:57:14.661: D/dalvikvm(1263): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-18 06:57:14.671: D/dalvikvm(1263): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-18 06:57:14.701: D/dalvikvm(1263): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-18 06:57:14.701: D/dalvikvm(1263): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-18 06:57:15.411: D/AndroidRuntime(1263): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
06-18 06:57:15.421: D/dalvikvm(1263): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 157 unimplemented (abstract) methods
06-18 06:57:15.452: I/ActivityManager(274): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.virginmobileinfo/.MainActivity} from pid 1263
06-18 06:57:15.502: D/AndroidRuntime(1263): Shutting down VM
06-18 06:57:15.522: D/dalvikvm(1263): GC_CONCURRENT freed 95K, 17% free 499K/596K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 11ms
06-18 06:57:15.522: D/jdwp(1263): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
06-18 06:57:15.522: D/dalvikvm(1263): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-18 06:57:15.661: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-18 06:57:16.791: I/Process(1232): Sending signal. PID: 1232 SIG: 9
06-18 06:57:16.812: I/ActivityManager(274): Process com.example.virginmobileinfo (pid 1232) has died.
06-18 06:57:16.831: D/dalvikvm(1273): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
06-18 06:57:16.852: I/ActivityManager(274): Start proc com.example.virginmobileinfo for activity com.example.virginmobileinfo/.MainActivity: pid=1273 uid=10049 gids={50049, 1028}
06-18 06:57:17.341: E/Trace(1273): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-18 06:57:17.651: D/dalvikvm(1273): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 96K, 8% free 2566K/2784K, paused 32ms, total 35ms
06-18 06:57:17.661: I/dalvikvm-heap(1273): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.227MB for 635812-byte allocation
06-18 06:57:17.721: D/dalvikvm(1273): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 7% free 3185K/3408K, paused 60ms, total 60ms
06-18 06:57:17.761: D/dalvikvm(1273): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 3186K/3408K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 41ms
06-18 06:57:17.831: D/AndroidRuntime(1273): Shutting down VM
06-18 06:57:17.831: W/dalvikvm(1273): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.virginmobileinfo/com.example.virginmobileinfo.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:439)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.post(HttpConnection.java:173)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.example.virginmobileinfo.minuteschecker.UserData.DownloadUserProfile(UserData.java:31)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.example.virginmobileinfo.minuteschecker.UserData.LoadData(UserData.java:46)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.example.virginmobileinfo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:110)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-18 06:57:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     ... 11 more
06-18 06:57:17.881: W/ActivityManager(274):   Force finishing activity com.example.virginmobileinfo/.MainActivity
06-18 06:57:18.051: D/dalvikvm(274): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 661K, 24% free 7194K/9380K, paused 124ms, total 133ms
06-18 06:57:18.221: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-18 06:57:18.582: W/ActivityManager(274): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40f99c98 u0 com.example.virginmobileinfo/.MainActivity}
06-18 06:57:18.651: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-18 06:57:18.681: W/EGL_emulation(398): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-18 06:57:20.464: D/ExchangeService(633): Received deviceId from Email app: null
06-18 06:57:20.464: D/ExchangeService(633): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
```

Here is my class:

```
package com.example.virginmobileinfo.minuteschecker;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class UserData {

    private org.jsoup.nodes.Document vm_website_data;
    private String[] tags_to_load = {"first-name", "phone-number", "balance", "total", "start-date", "mins-used", "mins-left"};
    private String user_data_file_path = "user_data.txt";
    private String data_to_sort;

    /** Download latest profile source code */
    public String DownloadUserProfile(){
        //showDebugToast("Attempting to download profile...");
        vm_website_data = null; //declare variable
        try {
            //showDebugToast("Downloading profile...");
            vm_website_data = Jsoup.connect("https://www2.virginmobileusa.com/login/login.do")
                    .timeout(10*6000)
                    .data("min", "5555555555")
                    .data("vkey", "999999")
                    .data("submit", "submit")
                    .post();
            //showDebugToast("Profile downloaded!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //Return blank if can't download profile
        }
        //showDebugToast(vm_website_data.toString());
        return vm_website_data.toString(); //Return data if successful
    }


    /** Filter for usable data from VM website code */
    public void LoadData(){

        File file = new File(user_data_file_path);
        if(file.exists() == false){
            data_to_sort = DownloadUserProfile();
            data_to_sort = StringUtils.substringBetween(data_to_sort, "<vmu-page", "</vmu-page>");
        } else if(data_to_sort == null){
            try {
                data_to_sort = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //showDebugToast("Running filter...");

        /* Turn bulk info into pieces */
        String[] output_arr = new String[tags_to_load.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tags_to_load.length; i++){
            String tag_id = tags_to_load[i];
            String tag_contents = StringUtils.substringBetween(data_to_sort, "<" + tags_to_load[i] + ">", "</" + tag_id + ">");
            output_arr[i] = "<" + tag_id + ">" + tag_contents + "</" + tag_id + ">";
            //showDebugToast(tag_id + " : " + tag_contents);
        }

        /* Save file if it didn't exist in the first place */
        if(file.exists() == false){
            saveUserProfile(output_arr);
        }
    }

    public void saveUserProfile(String[] output_arr){
        //showDebugToast("Saving profile...");
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(user_data_file_path, "UTF-8");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.println(Arrays.toString(output_arr));
        writer.close();

        //showDebugToast("Profile saved!");
    }

    public void showDebugToast(String messageText){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), messageText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //System.out.println(messageText);
    }

}
```

**Edit:** The initial problem was UserData class was in launch configuration.  I took it out and called the method LoadData() from OnCreate() in MainActivity activity.

Comment: Do u run it as 'Android Application' ?

Comment: Yes.  Right now I'm just running the MainActivity, but even that won't run since I added my custom class to the app package.

Comment: It should be noted that I had NO PROBLEMS before I added this custom class to my eclipse project.

Comment: What you've just added is a thread dump not the stacktrace and not as helpful. You can find the stacktrace of your crash by looking at the logcat output which is separate from the console output or error files generated by the JVM.

Comment: Added logcat output.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android's entry point isn't `public static void main(String[] args)` like for a regular Java application, it uses Activities instead.

You should be putting your code inside an `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, `onStart()` or other applicable method in your Activity (or Fragment).

Read up on the [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [its lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) (and [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)) to see what gets executed when to choose where/when your code should be executed.

**Edit:** It is possible to have a class with a `main` method in Android but it takes some doing to get configured and almost certainly not what you were trying to do. Here is a [related Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10897920/1590950) ([and another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12878525/1590950)) on the topic in case you're interested.

**Edit2: Second issue**

Your stacktrace shows:

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    ...
    at com.example.virginmobileinfo.minuteschecker.UserData.DownloadUserProfile(UserData.java:31)
```

You are attempting to make network interactions on the UI thread which Android doesn't allow as it would make your app unresponsive for the duration of the call.

You need to look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or other background thread handling. The Android docs on the topic [are here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html)

Comment: dang, I meant to take that part out.  Thing is, even when I didn't have that part in it, I still couldn't let this class sit without the console spouting off errors.  Like I said, I hadn't even included it in my MainActivity yet. Why do you think that is?

Comment: If you make the changes to and then update your code above and post a stacktrace of the error we'd be more able to help you. Make sure to indicate any lines referenced in the error so we know where the problem likely lies.

Comment: I updated the OP to include a detailed log.  I'm not sure how to post a stacktrace, sorry for the additional question.

Comment: To get to logcat on Eclipse: `Window > Show View > Other > Logcat` and in Android Studio just click the `Android` that is in the bottom right of the window by default.

Comment: Thank you!! I will look into it, this looks promising.

Comment: Thank you for your help, indivisible. :)

Comment: @moatist, you're very welcome. Also, as you're just starting out I would recommend you follow the [example project](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) and [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) sections on the Android Dev site as it's a great introduction and overview to Android design, programming and best practices and, among other things, covers both of the issues you had..